# Excel - duplicate search and replace - 2 sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let me rephrase the question. When a cell in column A sheet 1 matches a cell in column A sheet 2, take the value on that row of sheet 2 column e and replace the value in column E sheet 1 with it on that row with the same value in column A.  I am trying to update sheet 1 with data that will be coming from sheet 2.  Column A is the unique identifier.

Comment: I think that you may need to clarify your question. Are you looking for Row by Row replacement if there is a match between Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 or are you considering an AND case where all Values in Column A on Sheet 1 must match all Values in Column A on Sheet 2 in order for replacement to take place for All cells in Column E.

Comment: I am looking for row by row. Each row will have different numbers and or text

Comment: Let me rephrase the question.  When a cell in column A sheet 1 matches a cell in column A sheet 2, take the value on that row of sheet 2 column e and replace the value in column E sheet 1 with it on that row with with the same value in column A.

Comment: Okay. @krowe 's answer should work then. It is probably easiest to implement like he said with a new column. You could do it with VBA if you didn't want to have the new column. The other alternative is to have a Sheet three which replicates Sheet 1 and you place the formula below in that sheets E column. You then have a sheet that has the correct formatting and value in column E without too much work.

Comment: The problem that I am seeing with that formula though is that the values that would match in column A wouldnt necessarily be on the same row number.  So if column A row 3 sheet 1 matches column A row 4 sheet 2.  I want the value in sheet 2 column e row 4 to dump into column e row 3 of sheet 1.

Comment: Are you saying that Sheet 2 is just offset by one row or that say Column A has a unique account number in it and you want to find that account number in Sheet 2, whatever row it is in, and if the value in Sheet 2 is different, then you want that value to appear in Sheet 1?

Comment: Sheet 1, column 1 = z123; column 2 = apple.  Find z123 on sheet 2 and take the value in column 2 and move it to sheet 1 column 2 on the same row as z123.

Comment: So long as the z123 is unique in column 1, then I would use a lookup as one of the arguments of your if statement. This will find your key, z123, an sheet two and return the value for comparison. If you have multiple instances of z123, then the problem becomes a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can create a new column, lets call it F, in Sheet1 and use the following formula for it:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1, Sheet2!E1, Sheet1!E1)
```

You cannot really use this directly in column E because that would be a circular reference. That is bad because the original data in Sheet1 column E is lost after the first invocation. You need the new column in order to keep the original data. Excel will allow it but the results are almost guaranteed to not be what you're expecting. You can hide the original Sheet1 column E by resizing it to 0 pixels wide and have a similar effect (it'll just skip over that column letter for display but it'll still be there to hold the original data).

Comment: The question isn't 100% clear as the OP uses "column." Your formula answer tests cells, but I can see where they might be thinking of an AND situation where all of the cells in Column A on Sheet 1 need to Match all of the cells on Column A on Sheet two in order for the replacement to occur.

Comment: I see what you mean. It hadn't occurred to me that (s)he may want all cells in the column to be the same. I think though, that Google won't know the difference between those two questions no matter how they are written so this will be useful to someone (just maybe not the OP)

Comment: Instead of going through the whole sort of hiding a column, which is a bad idea (see this story about hiding things on spreadsheets [link](http://www.businessinsider.com/2008/10/barclays-excel-error-results-in-lehman-chaos)), you can just make a 'presentation' Sheet 3 that references all of the data in Sheet 1 and has your formula in column E. Just write protect it so someone trying to make a change will realize that they need to do it in a different sheet.

Comment: @AMR Very good tip about using a scratch worksheet. In many situations, that is clearly the superior way to do this sort of thing. In this particular case, I'd say it could go either way. It may be helpful to see, at a glance, which items are actually being counted. In that case the hidden column is best because it can be easily unhidden. If you will never care about that then you may as well put it on a scratch sheet so that it stays out of the way and doesn't cause trouble with any scripts you may be using.

Comment: @AMR The link you gave is not something I'd take too seriously. Why would entire accounts be hidden in in columns for one? Clearly, the way this should be arranged is one account per line. Something just doesn't jive here and I believe that this was just a very inexperienced Excel user whom should've never been in charge of the final draft of something like this. I would blame this on a lot of things but hidden columns is not very high on that list. Leaving a few pixels show is perhaps a good idea though, just so that you don't forget about the column.

Comment: I worked for one of the companies involved... I know it happened. Yes it was an overworked analyst, and yes it should have been caught, but during the debt crisis those things could bring down or cause serious damage to a major institution. Hiding anything is a bad practice for spreadsheet design. If you want different formatting, then set it up on a different sheet and refer back to the data from a separate, preferably write protected sheet. I actually used to have VBA build and lock everything for me on a daily basis. All of the code was proofed and password protected. Can't be too careful.